# Displaying an NSArray list from inside an NSDictionary?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray, nsdictionary

I'm working on an app for personal use that displays lists of associated words randomly.

With help from this community I've put lists of associated words into NSArrays. For example:

```
NSArray *catList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Lion", @"Snow Leopard", @"Cheetah", nil];
NSArray *dogList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Dachshund", @"Pitt Bull", @"Pug", nil]; 
...
```

And I've put those arrays into an NSDictionary:

```
 NSMutableDictionary *wordDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [wordDictionary setObject: catList forKey:@"Cats"];
        [wordDictionary setObject: dogList forKey:@"Dogs"]; 
...
```

What I'd like to do is randomly select one of the NSDictionary keys and display the list of NSStrings held in its array. Obviously `[wordDictionary objectForKey: @"Cats"];` allows me to access the catList array set to the Cats key to display the string list held in the array. But I'd like to display the lists randomly and without specifying the key.

I experimented with `[wordDictionary allKeys]` and could randomly display the name of a key but not the list held in the array.

Does anyone have any pointers for displaying an NSArray list from an NSDictionary?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
NSInteger keyCount = [[wordDictionary allKeys] count];
NSInteger randomKeyIndex = random() % keyCount;
NSString *randomKey = [[wordDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:randomKeyIndex];
NSArray *randomlySelectedArray = [wordDictionary objectForKey:randomKey];
```

Comment: Wow that was fast. That's exactly what I needed. Thanks a million @bneely! If you wouldn't mind my asking, how long have you been coding? I just started two weeks ago and it's fun, though daunting. Are there any go-to objective-c resources you would recommend? Thanks again.

Comment: I've been programming on a part-time basis for almost 11 years, and fulltime for two months. Big Nerd Ranch is a company that does training and publishes programming books; I have read through two of their books and completed all of the assignments. Good luck!